# Unable to connect and create bucket in google cloud storage via java sdk

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am unable to create a google cloud storage bucket using the java sdk, below is the code I am using:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

         String projectId = "**********";

         Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
            Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();

            for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
              System.out.println(bucket.getName());
            }

      }
}
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

> Caused by:
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
>   Unauthorized {   "code" : 401,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "location" : "Authorization",
>       "locationType" : "header",
>       "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 833568054484.",
>       "reason" : "required"   } ],   "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 833568054484." }

Comment: Clearly, you are trying to list the bucket without authenticating, and the anonymous user doesn't have access to do that.

Comment: @StephenC but the project id has the necessary permission                                                 String projectId = "**********";

   Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
      Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();

      for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
        System.out.println(bucket.getName());
      }

Comment: Do I have to do anything apart from giving permission to the project id which I use?

Comment: 1)  Put the code into the question.  2)  Clearly, the error you are getting back is saying that you have not authenticated. And an unauthenticated user cannot do what you are trying to do.  You need to authenticate.

Comment: how do I authenticate?

Comment: The code that you have shown uses ADC (Application Default Credentials). You must setup your environment correctly. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

You are not authenticating, you can check how to add permissions to your bucket on the [Using Cloud IAM permissions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions).

If you want to give access to authenticated users you have to select the user group `allAuthenticatedUsers` and give them the `Storage Object Viewer` Role. This will allow all authenticated users, even anonymously, view/list permissions in your bucket.

NOTE: As you can see on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam), the `allAuthenticatedUsers` member types should only be used when it is acceptable for anyone on the Internet to read and analyze your data. So you should consider a different access management type if that is not the case for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.[Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)

2.[Creating a service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) for the service account just created. Remember the path where you store the key.json file.

3.[Assign to the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) the role Storage Admin

4.[Provide credentials to your application](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

a. Using env variable

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

b. Explicit in code

```
static void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
  // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
  // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
  GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
  Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

  System.out.println("Buckets:");
  Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
  for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println(bucket.toString());
  }
}
```